# Fridge starting up turns TV on/off

Tags: electrical

I think this is simply because its old, but whenever the fridge "kicks on", it being on the same circuit as the TV makes the TV turn off/back on.  Just curious if there is anything I can do other than a new fridge or getting them off the same circuit (not possible).  Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Could be this: http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/28002/23448

Comment: it could be the starting cap on the compressor, if it has gone bad the motor will work really hard for a lot longer to get to speed and draws down the line. this would be my first item to look at

Comment: @mbeckish, agreed. I would about guarantee it is on the same circuit.

Comment: @mbeckish, yeah, that sounds like it.  Unfortunately, being on another circuit is not an option (out in the countryside of France, in a house with a wide open floor plan, so the wires go around the house with zero plugs that are not on this circuit).  And this fridge is old, so I'll bet its just pulling more when it kicks on.  I'll see if I can find a voltage stabilizer.

Answer (score 2):

Your cheapest option besides a new fridge might be a UPS for the TV.

Make sure you get at least a line interactive type. The offline / standby versions will just pass the dropout spike through to the TV. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply#Line-interactive

My neighborhood power had some lines rubbing together when it was windy. The power would drop just for an instant but long enough to reset my TiVo causing a 5 minute dropout in any program I was recording. I got a UPS for it and solved the problem until the power company fixed the lines.

Electronics are sensitive to even the shortest drop in power. A UPS could smooth out the spikes and let your TV ride through the dropouts.
Good luck!

Comment: If the fridge is what's occasionally drawing more power, wouldn't it make more sense to put the Fridge on the UPS?

Answer (score 0):

Get a Surge & Brown-out power strip, kind of tough to find but that might be enough. Or, do what other people do, which isn't really the safest conditions. Run an extension cord from another outlet on a different circuit. Make sure the run doesn't cross any door ways or traffic areas & rides the wall(s).

Other than that, you could get an electrician & see if the fridge circuit could be refreshed with a new outlet or higher rated one. Which leads to my next point. If this situation hasn't always been present & is fairly recent. Then, an Appliance Repairer might be the real solution. Your compressor motor might be starting to fail & pulling much more power than it should be.